# Weird markup appearing on the page for my jsfiddle

Tags: html

Why for this fiddle is the weird markup below appearing on the page? Ive tried validating it and I cant see what the issue is, I dont normally add a doc type to a fiddle and its normally ok.

http://jsfiddle.net/eX8zY/7/

```
jsFiddle demo   /* test */ * { display: inline-block; } .error { color: red; } label { color: blue; clear: left; } input { color: gold; } //<![CDATA[ window.addEvent('load', function() { });//]]>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug with star selector in css. You probably got to report it in fiddle support/bug section.